# macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 - reset sidebar to default

Tags: macos, finder

Is there a way to reset the sidebar in the finder to the default?

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```

doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no com.apple.sidebar.plist in Sonoma. You probably need to delete the com.apple.finder.plist.

click in Finder: Go > Go To Folder...
and enter this text:
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

Hit Enter. Move the file to the Trash and Reboot.

now re enter the desired preferences in Finder > Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rm` command is the right one.

Next you have to restart the `Finder`:

- hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>
- select `Finder`, and then click [Relaunch].

Upon restarting `Finder` will try to open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`  and will recreate it.